# Смена клавиатуры в Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Хочу добиться того, что бы при использование команды "Счетчик" мой телеграм бот удалял старую Репли-Клавиатуру и добавлял новую Инлайн-Клавиатуру к отправленному сообщению, однако встретился с проблемой - в параметр `reply_markup` могу добавить либо `ReplyKeyboardRemove()`, либо `сounter_ikb`(Моя инлайн клавиатура). Но не оба значения.

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Счетчик'))
async def counter_handler(message: types.Message):
    global counter
    await message.answer(f'Счетчик = {counter}', reply_markup=сounter_ikb)
    await message.delete()
```

Результатом работы моего кода является добавление Инлайн-Клавиатуры, но не удаление старой Репли-Клавиатуры.
`Бот - @learnandtest123_bot`